# drf_yasg: How to add square brackets in TYPE_ARRAY parameters when request from swagger ui

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I have custom field in request body:

```
    receipt_details_schema = openapi.Schema(
        type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT,
        properties={
                'bonus_restrict': openapi.Schema(
                    title='bonus_restrict',
                    type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER
                ),
                'prod_cat': openapi.Schema(
                    title='prod_cat',
                    type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER
                ),
                'prod_code': openapi.Schema(
                    title='prod_code',
                    type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER
                ),
                'prod_name': openapi.Schema(
                    title='prod_name',
                    type=openapi.TYPE_STRING
                ),
                'prod_price': openapi.Schema(
                    title='prod_price',
                    type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER
                ),
                'prod_amount': openapi.Schema(
                    title='prod_amount',
                    type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER
                ),
                'prod_sum': openapi.Schema(
                    title='prod_sum',
                    type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER
                ),
                'position': openapi.Schema(
                    title='position',
                    type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER
                ),
        },
        required=['prod_code', 'prod_price', 'prod_amount', 'prod_sum', 'position'],
    )

    receipt_details_field = openapi.Parameter(
        name='receipt_details',
        in_=openapi.IN_FORM,
        description="receipt_details field",

        type=openapi.TYPE_ARRAY,
        items=receipt_details_schema
        # schema=receipt_details_schema,

    )

    @swagger_auto_schema(manual_parameters=[receipt_details_field])
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
```

and when trying request from swagger ui with header(x-www-urlencoded), i get data field whithout square backet. How i can add it with objects when requesting?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qU60.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBWMZ.png)

I check drf_yasg documentation and not find answer for my quetion. I'm beginner in drf, dont scold me.